# Vista's chkdsk just deleted lots files - can i recover them?

Tags: windows-vista, chkdsk

I didnt know it was going to delete stuff! it didnt even ask me if it was ok to. But it went and deleted a lot of photos and music off my harddrive.

Is there anyway i can recover them?

Answer (score 2):

For recovery deleted files you can use [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)

It's Freeware

Description from the site:

> Accidentally deleted an important file? Lost something important when your computer crashed? No problem! Recuva recovers files deleted from your Windows computer, Recycle Bin, digital camera card, or MP3 player. And it's free!

Answer (score 0):

Your files were likely corrupted and were therefore unusable even before the chkdsk. chkdsk simply found the corrupted files and deleted them. It is possible, though highly improbable, that the files were not very highly corrupted; you can try using a file recovery tool. (I'm pretty sure that a bunch of comments will spring up around this saying what is the best). Oh yeah, one more thing:

**STOP USING THE COMPUTER FOR THE BEST CHANCE OF FILE RECOVERY!!**